# Structuring my React/Redux app for efficiency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Im building an audio workstation app that will display a table of tracks containing clips. Right now I have a table reducer which returns a table object. The table object contains track objects and the track objects contain clip objects. I have a TableContainer which subscribes to the table store. My issue is I believe my app will be inefficient because it will re render the page every time a clip is added or manipulated. In reality only the particular track in which the clip resides would need to be re rendered right? How can I structure my app so not every little change re renders the entire app?

Answer (score 2):

In the `mapStateToProps` of any component, don't select parent objects as a whole to send to the component. If possible select specific properties all the way to the leaf values. If your `TableContainer`'s `render()` itself doesn't use the `tracks` array them make sure only the sibling properties that you do use get passed.

So instead of:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    table: state.tables[props.tableId];
  }
}
```

Do:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  let table = state.tables[props.tableId];
  return {
    name: table.name, 
    type: table.type
  };
```

This allows React Redux to be more discerning when it comes to determining whether your component needs to be rerendered. It will see that even though the `table` had changed due to a `clip` change, neither the `name`, nor the `type` has changed.

However, since your `Table`component likely renders the `Track` components as well, you're likely not going to be able to avoid render calls. If any property anywhere up the tree gets altered, the `tracks` array also gets altered.

The solution in this case is to have the `tracks`array not contain the entire `track` object but instead only a list of track IDs. You can then store the tracks alongside the tables and a change in one won't affect the other. Note that this only works if you do not go and fetch and pass the track object in the `mapStateToProps` of the `Table` component. You should make the`Track` component in such a way that it accepts its ID instead of the actual object as a prop. This way the `Table` component is not dependent on the contents of the tracks at all.

Comment: what if I need information thats not important for rendering the page. Like  a clip needs to know where the other clips are on the track but it doesn't need to re render when a clip moves.

Answer (score 1):

The power of react is to re-render only what needs to be (by using the virtual DOM to make the comparison and the `shouldComponentUpdate` function).

I wouldn't look too much into it before it becomes a performance problem.

If it does, I would store the tracks in a separate directory and don't pass it to the app (main) component. In your `Clip` component's `mapStateToProps` function (if you use react-redux), fetch the track from the state as you get it's name from the props. This way if the track changes a lot (because of async fetching of slices for example), only the component will update.